# PowerShell $Script:info["VARIABLE"] > Cannot index into a null array

Tags: powershell

I'm getting errors saving credentials to cache, this doesn't seem to work while $response is valid and tokens have been received.

Does anybody know how this **$Script:** part is supposed to work? I can't find anything about it..

> $Script:refresh_tokens["$ClientId-$Resource"] = $response.refresh_token

> Cannot index into a null array.
> At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AADInternals\0.6.6\AccessToken.ps1:1601 char:13
> $Script:tokens["$ClientId-$Resource"] =         $response ...
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

> $Script:refresh_tokens["$ClientId-$Resource"] = $response.refresh_token

> Cannot index into a null array.
> At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AADInternals\0.6.6\AccessToken.ps1:1601 char:13
> $Script:tokens["$ClientId-$Resource"] =         $response ...
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

https://github.com/Gerenios/AADInternals/blob/master/AccessToken_utils.ps1

Comment: `$script:` is a _scope modifier_ - it's telling PowerShell "this variable was defined in a parent scope, but I want to update it from here". BUT, inside a module-bound command, script-scope is the same as _module-scope_, so those references only work when you've imported the containing module, it might not work as expected when you extract the function definitions from the module.

Comment: Yes that is it, thanks! Now how do I mark this as answer?

Answer (score 0):

$script: is a scope modifier - it's telling PowerShell "this variable was defined in a parent scope, but I want to update it from here". BUT, inside a module-bound command, script-scope is the same as module-scope, so those references only work when you've imported the containing module, it might not work as expected when you extract the function definitions from the module. –
Mathias R. Jessen